# Spring Job Response To Client

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, javafx-8, spring-batch

Spring batch job runs to completion successfully with following code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/jobs")
public class JobLaunchingController {
    @Autowired
    private JobOperator jobOperator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pay/{paymentPeriod}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void launchPaymentJob(@PathVariable Integer paymentPeriod) throws Exception {
        this.jobOperator.start("paymentJob", String.format("paymentPeriod=%s,time=" + System.currentTimeMillis(), paymentPeriod));
    }
}
```

I am using JavaFX client where the endpoint is used to send request for the job to be launched. Basically, with the help of jersey client http request is sent like so

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(getBaseUri()).path(path);
Response response = webTarget.request().get(Response.class);
```

The problem is i don't have a way for the client to know when the job is complete. How can client be notified by server when job is done

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried jms for your application?

Comment: u can send a simple email or can implement jms in your code or u can use firebase

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it helped you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a architectural question than coding. You can solve this by multiple ways, I will suggest you below three

1. Simplest -> If your jobs doesn't take long - make your client wait for the outcome of job. Send them final status back in response.
2. Send job reference number immediately to client and introduce another endpoint where client can check with reference number if jobs is done - This involves your client having some polling mechanism.
3. Use something like Server Sent Events/Websockets - Thanks [cerp0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5380322/cepr0)

Answer (score 0):

> How can client be notified by server when job is done?

Try to use Websokets to send data from server to client. [Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) is a pretty good guide how to do it with Spring.

On the client side I believe you can use this approach: https://github.com/nickebbutt/stomp-websockets-java-client